# How to count remaining days in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My goal is to make a column in phpMyAdmin, which counts down the remaining days of a trial period (or something like that).

So for example when I set remainingDays to 30, **I want the database to execute the query every 24 hrs**

Is it possible to make something like this with only phpMyAdmin in hand, or do I have to put some code onto my website to send MySql Commands to subtract it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A virtual column?

Comment: what do you mean by 'virtual column'?

Comment: This is wrong approach. You need not count down, just on insert set end trial period date, and you can to show remaining days

Comment: As its name suggests, PHPMyAdmin is simply an admin tool for MySQL, built in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to have a `startDate` column compute the remaining days during query execution with something like:

```
select 30-datediff(now(),startDate) from...
```

Comment: Yeah I just figured how to approach my plan. But how do you execute this query every 24 hours?

Comment: There's no need to update anything if you compute days remaining at execution, the database just needs to remember when you started the promotional period

Comment: Thanks, but when the trial ends, the value just goes negative. How do I set it to display zero?

Comment: `select greatest(30-datediff(now(),startDate),0) from...`

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with `datediff()`?  Something like:

```
select datediff(target_date, curdate()) as days_remaining
from t;
```

That is, you can do this in a SQL query.